# Qual é a diferença entre utilizar += e =+ no Python?

Tags: python, operadores, sintaxe

Estou com dificuldade em entender a diferença de lógica entre:

```
x += n
```

E:

```
x =+ n
```

Comment: Você viu a segunda opção em algum lugar ou testou por conta e não entendeu porque o resultado é diferente?

Comment: Aliás, editei colocando um título mais condizente com a sua pergunta.

Comment: Se uma das respostas abaixo resolveu o seu problema e não restou nenhuma dúvida, escolha a que você mais gostou e marque-a como correta/aceita ao clicar no "✅" que está ao lado dela, o que também marca a sua pergunta como resolvida. Se ainda te resta alguma dúvida ou gostaria de maiores esclarecimentos, fique a vontade para comentar. 

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A resposta é: **depende**.

As respostas do [Maniero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/423669/5878) e do [Luan](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/423672/5878) valem somente quando as variáveis em questão são numéricas.

O primeiro trecho de código, `x += n`, é o equivalente a fazer `x = x + n`. O resultado dependerá de quem são `x` e `n`. Se forem numéricos, serão somados; se forem *strings* serão concatenados; se forem listas serão mescladas, etc. É o que chamamos de [*in-place operator*](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/operator.html#in-place-operators).

Em termos de API do Python, fazer `x += n` é o mesmo que `x = x.__iadd__(n)`, ou seja, se `x` for instância de uma classe definida pelo usuário, o comportamento de `+=` pode ser diferente do "esperado".

Já o segundo trecho, `x =+ n` é o mesmo que `x = +n`; ou seja, está fazendo uma atribuição em `x` com o retorno do operador `+` em `n`. Se `n` for numérico, retornará o próprio valor sem modificar o sinal; se `n` for *string* dará erro.

Em termos de API do Python, fazer `+n` é o mesmo que `pos(n)`, que é o mesmo que `n.__pos__()`; ou seja, o valor retornado dependerá do método `__pos__` do objeto. Também, se `n` for definido pelo usuário, o retorno de `+n` pode ser diferente do "esperado".

Todo esse comportamento é definido pela [*Data Model*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html), em que é feita a transferência de responsabilidade da linguagem para o objeto. Não é o interpretador que definirá qual é o resultado do operador, mas sim o próprio objeto; ou seja, é possível você implementar estruturas que fogem completamente do esperado, como por exemplo `-x` retornando o dobro de `x`, `+x` retornando uma lista, etc.

```py
class NonSense:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __neg__(self):
        return 2*self.value

    def __pos__(self):
        return [1, 2, 3]

x = NonSense(2)

print(-x)  # 4
print(+x)  # [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: É a resposta mas correta... +1

Comment: @fernandosavio Puxa saco xD

Comment: Tem que deixar registrado antes que marquem a mais votada como correta. hahaha

Answer (score 7):

Estou considerando que está usando um tipo numérico padrão existente em Python, com outro tipo de dado pode dar outro resultado ou erro.

O primeiro está somando o valor de `n` ao valor `x` já existente e guardando em `x`mesmo, porque este é o operador composto de adição, portanto ele é uma acumulador, não é uma adição simples porque ele guarda o valor, ele faz uma atribuição junto da adição. É o mesmo que fazer:

```
x = x + n
```

O segundo deveria ser escrito de um outro jeito para ser mais legível:

```
x = +n
```

Ou melhor ainda:

```
x = n
```

que é a mesma coisa, o sinal aí não faz algo útil e não precisa ou não deveria ser usado.

Quando escreve `=+` não está usando um operador, mas sim dois, sem um espaço para separá-los. Que é o oposto de `+=` que é um operador só. Há uma definição na gramática da linguagem que indica isso. Por isso que acho que algumas linguagens deveriam obrigar espaço em certos lugares, assim não geraria confusão.

O `+` aí é um operador unário (só tem um operando).

Este código só está atribuindo (`=`) o valor de `n` na variável `x`. O sinal de `+` ali não é adição é apenas para confirmar que o valor deve se manter igual ao que era, assim como você pode usar `-` para indicar que o valor é negativado, portanto é um inversor de sinal.

Ele não tem função alguma. Alguns podem achar que fica mais legível, mas esta pergunta mostra que confunde mais que ajuda. Algumas linguagens estão preferindo nem poder escrever um código assim (algumas se arrependeram de ter criado este operador inútil), então não ter a possibilidade de colocar um `+` antes de valores ou variáveis só para indicar o sinal e não sendo parte de uma operação aritmética de adição.

Este operador assim é apenas um confirmador de sinal, ou seja, o valor manterá o sinal que já tinha, então se era positivo continua positivo e se era negativo continua negativo. E tem outro operador antes que é a atribuição simples.

O operador que inverte o sinal tem utilidade, seria algo assim:

```
x = -n
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Operator/Compound.py).

Neste caso estaria atribuindo para `x` o valor invertido de `n`, portanto seria um valor negativo se `n` por positivo ou seria positivo se `n` fosse negativo.

É matemática pura, mais com mais dá mais, mais com menos dá menos (não importa qual vem primeiro), e menos com menos dá mais.

Comment: Apesar de nunca ter visto em código real, vale mencionar que `+n` pode ser sobrecarregado, se o objeto implementar o método `__pos__` - então, estritametne falando `+n` e `n` não são equivalentes.  (este comentário é o suficiente para marcar essa diferença no entanto - o texto da resposta está bem legal já).

Comment: @jsbueno por isso eu coloquei que só vale para os tipos numéricos da linguagem. Tem outra resposta que já completa para esses casos teóricos possíveis mas que não acontecem de fato e que até já tem outras respostas (o foco aqui é o operador unário). Talvez alguém tenha visto como erro eu não descrever em detalhes a exceção e por isso negativou.

Answer (score 4):

1.`x += n` é uma abreviação de x = x + n

2.`x =+ n` é uma abreviação de x = (+n)

logo o primeiro indica a soma do atributo x com o atributo n, ja o segundo indica que o atributo x vai receber o valor n de forma positiva, por exemplo

`x =+ 5` o elemento x ira receber o 5 como +5 pois o `=+`de indicar o valor como positivo.